# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' .. C:\xampp\..PDOStatement->fetch().. on line 83

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have actually seen similar questions on this "**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'"**.

But I have not been able to use have I have seen to resolve the challenge am having.

Below are the code and the error message

```
<?php 
$sql5 = " set @rownum := 0; 
set @sum := 0;

select DISTINCT(ROUND(the_avg,4))
 FROM (
    select water_level, 
@rownum := (@rownum + 1) as rownum, 
@sum := IF(@rownum mod 7 = 1,0 + water_level,@sum + water_level) as running_sum,
IF(@rownum mod 7 = 0,@sum / 7,NULL) as the_avg
FROM " .$table." WHERE record_month_year = '".$startDateReport."'
order by id ASC
) s ";
$result5 = $db->prepare($sql5);
$result5->execute();
while ($rowReport = $result5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
        <td><?php echo $rowReport['the_avg'] ; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

**The line 83 is :**

```
while ($rowReport = $result5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

**error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\awos\includes\loadboreholedatareport.php:83 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\awos\includes\loadboreholedatareport.php(83): PDOStatement->fetch() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\awos\borData-report.php(46): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\awos\includes\loadboreholedatareport.php on line 83.

Comment: Your query fails. You can only execute one query at a time. `set @rownum := 0;` is a query. Also didn't look through the rest of the query too much, could be something else wrong there; presumed you tested that before hand in phpmyadmin or somewhere. You could use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php. But you should use parameterized queries with your prepared statements. Currently, `$startDateReport` is not parameterized. php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Hi chris85, thanks for your quick response, I actually tested it on phpmyadmin

Comment: On phpmyadmin you can execute multiple queries at once by default. General PDO usage doesn't allow that. It is a security issue because a SQL injection could do anything at that point. So also be aware of the when using the `multi-query` function.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I actually tested it on phpmyadmin with the code below `code` set @rownum := 0;
set @sum := 0;
select DISTINCT(ROUND(the_avg,4))
from (
  select water_level,
  @rownum := (@rownum + 1) as rownum, 
  @sum := IF(@rownum mod 7 = 1,0 + water_level,@sum + water_level) as running_sum,
  IF(@rownum mod 7 = 0,@sum / 7,NULL) as the_avg
  from bore_hole_data
  order by id ASC
) s`code` and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: Umm yea...are you reading my comments?

Comment: yea, just saw it now

Comment: So how can I overcome this challenge

Comment: You could wrap all that code in a stored procedure, and then PDO will allow you to call it with a single statement.

Comment: Hi Adelphia, thanks for sharing, I have tried your suggestion out, am getting a different erro message now. the new error message `code` Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on integer in C:\xampp\htdocs\awos\includes\loadboreholedatareport.php on line 96 `code` and this is line `code` while ($rowReport = $result5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`code`

Answer (score 0):

You can only do one query at a time with PDO.. Do them separately, like this..

```
   $db->query("set @rownum := 0"); 
    $db->query("set @sum := 0");
    $sql5 = "select DISTINCT(ROUND(the_avg,4))
     FROM (
        select water_level, 
    @rownum := (@rownum + 1) as rownum, 
    @sum := IF(@rownum mod 7 = 1,0 + water_level,@sum + water_level) as running_sum,
    IF(@rownum mod 7 = 0,@sum / 7,NULL) as the_avg
    FROM " .$table." WHERE record_month_year = '".$startDateReport."'
    order by id ASC
    ) s ";
```

And the rest would be the same.

Comment: Hi Adelphia, thanks for sharing, I have tried your suggestion out, am getting a different erro message now. the new error message `code` Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on integer in C:\xampp\htdocs\awos\includes\loadboreholedatareport.php on line 96 `code` and this is line `code` while ($rowReport = $result5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`code`

Comment: @Gifto, please only one question at a time. I'll be happy to help but you need to select my answer and post a new question first.

Comment: I have been able to create a store procedure, and like i mentioned earlier am getting a different error now. `code` Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on integer in .. on line 99 `code` which is `code` while ($rowReport = $result5->query('select @out')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { `code`